# React Typescript - Binding element 'C' implicitly has an 'any' type. TS7031

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an issue converting js to ts format regarding a react component.

The error is

> Binding element 'C' implicitly has an 'any' type.  TS7031

It happens on the argument C of this function:

```
export default function UnauthenticatedRoute({ component: C, appProps, ...rest }:
                                                 RouteProps & {appProps: AppProps}) {
  const redirect = querystring("redirect");
  return (
    <Route {...rest}
        render={ props => !appProps.isAuthenticated ?
            <C {...props} {...appProps} />
          :
            <Redirect to={redirect === "" || redirect === null ? "/" : redirect}/>
        }
    />
  );
}
```

As I understand it, the component key in RouteProps which looks like this:

> component?: React.ComponentType<RouteComponentProps> |
> React.ComponentType;

is not typed enough.

How can I address this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

Since C is a component, not a prop.
So we may define the `UnauthenticatedRoute` component with two separate params to handle it.

```
interface RouteProps {}
interface AppProps {
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
}
interface Props {}

const UnauthenticatedRoute = (
  { appProps, ...rest }: RouteProps & { appProps: AppProps },
  C: React.ComponentType<Props>
) => {
  const redirect = queryString("redirect");
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        !appProps.isAuthenticated ? (
          <C {...props} {...appProps} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={redirect === "" || redirect === null ? "/" : redirect}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

You can try it online here:

[image: Edit naughty-shadow-b4bmj]

#### Origin

You may want to use `React.ComponentType`

```
export const UnauthenticatedRoute = <P extends object>(Component: React.ComponentType<P>, ...
```

then you can use it as a normal typed component

```
render() {
  return <Component {...this.props as P} />;
}
```

Kindly refer to this lib's source [react-debounce-rendering](https://github.com/ibarapascal/react-debounce-rendering/blob/master/lib/index.tsx)

And the article about `React.ComponentType` in [react-higher-order-component-patterns-in-typescript](https://medium.com/@jrwebdev/react-higher-order-component-patterns-in-typescript-42278f7590fb)

Comment: The render function does not return a component directly as you may see in the code I posted, so it does not work. I tried to apply what is explained in the article but to no avail.

Comment: @unludo Updated, if there are other limits, kindly let me know :)

Comment: That's good thanks. It's quite different from the origin article though.